# php - shell_exec , exec, etc.. can not get output like in terminal. even with 2>&1

Tags: php, shell-exec

First let's run the command via terminal:

```
$ echo 1; /etc/init.d/apache3 restart; echo 2;
```

result.. ( apache3 on purpose to see an error )

```
1
bash: /etc/init.d/apache3: No such file or directory
2
```

awsome.

now let's run this via php..

```
<?php

$command = "echo 1; /etc/init.d/apache3 restart; echo 2; 2>&1";
$response = shell_exec("$command");
echo $response;

?>
```

all I see on the browser is: `1 2`

I tried all sorts of things. replaced the semi colons with "&&"..
tried all the php stuff such as..

```
passthru()
exec()
system()
popen()
```

i tried it all pretty much. been hours.. can not get it to show me the same stuff i see via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 2>&1 after the restart command

Your command :

```
$command = "echo 1; /etc/init.d/apache3 restart; echo 2; 2>&1";
```

yours has "2>&1" at the end which has no use.

Also you will add to 2>&1 after each command in case others uses STDERR

```
$command = "echo 1; /etc/init.d/apache3 restart 2>&1; echo 2 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using exec. The basis function only returns the *first line* of the output:

```
$response = exec("$command"); // just the first line
```

But use the additional parameters to capture both the output (as an array) and the return value

```
$retval = NULL;
$output = NULL;
$response = shell_exec("$command", $output, $retval); // last two params are passed by reference and modified by the command
```

Also, as user993553 posted, the output captured by these cli functions in PHP will usually just return stdout and not stderr. You can append " 2>&1" to any given command (note the space before the 2) in order to route stderr into the output.

That said, your function becomes:

```
$command = "echo 1; /etc/init.d/apache3 restart 2>&1; echo 2;";
$retval = NULL;
$output = NULL;
$response = exec($command, $output, $retval);
var_dump($output);
```

and the output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "1"
  [1] =>
  string(37) "sh: 1: /etc/init.d/apache3: not found"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

EDIT: you can also check $retval for an error condition. If it's not empty or zero, then signifies an error.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual of shell_exec:

> ALSO, note that shell_exec() does not grab STDERR, so use "2>&1" to
>   redirect it to STDOUT and catch it.